# Adding to an array and nested array conditionally - Angular

Tags: javascript

I have a data model with a years array and within, a nested months array. I am pushing a new month to the year that is specified in the input box, So if the user specifies May for 2020, it goes as May for the 2020 array. However, if the year doesn't exist, (say for instance, he is the first user to add to the array on January 1st of 2022), then it needs to unshift the year 2022 to the main array and add January (or whatever month) inside that 2022 nested structure.

Here is how I have it so that it detects the year and add to that year (modified for console log and no html, but it works with inputs just fine)

```js
const journalentries = [
      { 
        "id": "2000001",
        "year": "2021", 
        "months": [
          {
            "year": "2021", 
            "month": "January", 
            "link": "Jan_Feb_2021"
          },
          {
            "year": "2021", 
            "month": "February",
            "link": "Jan_Feb_2021"
          },
          {
            "year": "2021", 
            "month": "December",
            "link": ""
          }
        ]
      },
      { 
        "id": "2000002",
        "year": "2020", 
        "months": [
          {
            "year": "2020", 
            "month": "January", 
            "link": "Jan_Feb_2020"
          },
          {
            "year": "2020", 
            "month": "February",
            "link": "Jan_Feb_2020"
          },
          {
            "year": "2020", 
            "month": "December",
            "link": "Dec_2020"
          }
        ]
      },
];

const selectedYear = '2021';
const selectedMonth = 'May';
const selectedLink = 'May_Aug_2021';

journalentries.forEach(entry => {
   if (entry.year === selectedYear) {
       entry.months.push({
          year: selectedYear,
          month: selectedMonth,
          link: selectedLink
       });
    }
});

console.log(journalentries);
```

I tried this (adding May to 2022 which is a year that doesn't exist) and it added the year but not the other stuff inside the year

```js
const journalentries = [
  { 
    "id": "2000001",
    "year": "2021", 
    "months": [
      {
        "year": "2021", 
        "month": "January", 
        "link": "Jan_Feb_2021"
      },
      {
        "year": "2021", 
        "month": "February",
        "link": "Jan_Feb_2021"
      },
      {
        "year": "2021", 
        "month": "December",
        "link": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  { 
    "id": "2000002",
    "year": "2020", 
    "months": [
      {
        "year": "2020", 
        "month": "January", 
        "link": "Jan_Feb_2020"
      },
      {
        "year": "2020", 
        "month": "February",
        "link": "Jan_Feb_2020"
      },
      {
        "year": "2020", 
        "month": "December",
        "link": "Dec_2020"
      }
    ]
  },
];

const selectedYear = '2022';
const selectedMonth = 'May';
const selectedLink = 'May_Aug_2021';

journalentries.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.year === selectedYear) {
        entry.months.push({
          year: selectedYear,
          month: selectedMonth,
          link: selectedLink
        });
    } else {
        journalentries.unshift({
            year: selectedYear            
        })
        journalentries[0].months.push({
            year: selectedYear,
            month: selectedMonth,
            link: selectedLink
        });
    }
});

console.log(journalentries);
```

Comment: Can you post expected output?

Comment: use the snippet button to add runnable code (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356678/stack-overflow-run-code-snippet)

Comment: No worries guys, I figured it out. Thanks anyway. I'm not sure if I should delete the question or answer it or leave it for people ot answer it and get points for it lol

Comment: @LOTUSMUS If you figured it out, you can make an answer by yourself so other people with same problem can come and see.

Comment: @BaoHuynhLam Sounds good. I added the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so here is the answer. Sorry. I figured it out shortly after I asked

```js
const journalentries = [
  { 
    "id": "2000001",
    "year": "2021", 
    "months": [
      {
        "year": "2021", 
        "month": "January", 
        "link": "Jan_Feb_2021"
      },
      {
        "year": "2021", 
        "month": "February",
        "link": "Jan_Feb_2021"
      },
      {
        "year": "2021", 
        "month": "December",
        "link": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  { 
    "id": "2000002",
    "year": "2020", 
    "months": [
      {
        "year": "2020", 
        "month": "January", 
        "link": "Jan_Feb_2020"
      },
      {
        "year": "2020", 
        "month": "February",
        "link": "Jan_Feb_2020"
      },
      {
        "year": "2020", 
        "month": "December",
        "link": "Dec_2020"
      }
    ]
  },
];

const selectedYear = '2022';
const selectedMonth = 'May';
const selectedLink = 'May_Aug_2021';

let found = false;

journalentries.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.year === selectedYear) {
        entry.months.push({
          year: selectedYear,
          month: selectedMonth,
          link: selectedLink
        });

        found = true;
    }
});

if(!found) {
    journalentries.unshift({
        year: selectedYear,           
        months: []
    })
    journalentries[0].months.push({
        year: selectedYear,
        month: selectedMonth,
        link: selectedLink
    });
}

console.log(journalentries);
```

I created a found variable to isolate the forEach so that it fires only if the year is found in the forEach.

If it's not found, then add the new year to the top and create an empty array placeholder for the new year, month and link to be stored in.

That year will always be the first place in the array so  it is instantiated to 0. I don't have the need to add a passed year. But if that is in your requirements you can expand from this code easily, I reckon